# Identifying memory leak in python - Memory Profiler

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm new to Python and I'm currently working on solving problems to improve my coding skills. Currently I'm working on a question where I had to `stable sort` the input and output the reverse-stable sorted values. I've programmed it and executed the code in the website's online judge and for one test case (don't know the test case), I got `Memory Limit Exceeded` error. So after some research, I understood that there is a `memory leak` happening in the code and the code is not fully efficient. So I have installed the python's `memory_profiler` to monitoring memory consumption of a process as well as line-by-line analysis of memory consumption of my code.

Please find below the input details, code, output and the memory profiling analysis taken from the `memory_profiler`.

Input:

```
8
1 2
16 3
11 2
20 3
3 5
26 4
7 1
22 4
```

Code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
@profile
def test_1():
    print "Enter the number: "
    n = raw_input()
    k = []
    v = []
    print "Enter ID and M: "
    for i in range(0,int(n)):
        a, b = raw_input().split(' ')
        k.append(a)
        v.append(b)
    d = OrderedDict(zip(k,v))
    sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k,v):int(v), reverse=True)
    for i, j in sorted_items:
        print i, j

if __name__ == '__main__':
        test_1()
```

Output:

```
    Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     2   10.520 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     3                             def test_1():
     4   10.531 MiB    0.012 MiB        print "Enter the number: "
     5   10.551 MiB    0.020 MiB        n = raw_input()
     6   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB        k = []
     7   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB        v = []
     8   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB        print "Enter ID and M: "
     9   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB        for i in range(0,int(n)):
    10   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB                a, b = raw_input().split(' ')
    11   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB                k.append(a)
    12   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB                v.append(b)
    13
    14   10.551 MiB    0.000 MiB        d = OrderedDict(zip(k,v))
    15   10.555 MiB    0.004 MiB        sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k,v):int(v), reverse=True)
    16   10.555 MiB    0.000 MiB        for i, j in sorted_items:
    17   10.555 MiB    0.000 MiB                print i, j
```

Expected Output (I'm able to get the desired output):

```
3 5
26 4
22 4
16 3
20 3
1 2
11 2
7 1
```

Is this code not efficient for higher input or higher numbers? from the analysis I could see that there is only less memory utilized but for that particular test case, I could see that memory  utilization is more than 16MB. 
Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong. Is my approach wrong or flow is wrong? Could you please tell me why I'm not able to get the output as expected. Thanks in advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected output? And why do you think it should use less memory?

Comment: updated the question to display the expected output

Comment: Looks like your code is correct, as is my revised version. Since there is no way to know the test case (the person who designed this online course should really rethink this), let's just see whether scraping the lists and changing `range` to `xrange` will help.

Comment: Sure, i'll try to execute the code with `xrange` and see the execution time and memory it is giving in the result.

Comment: un-fortunately, this time too memory limit exceeded - `Memory limit exceeded  0.374 16628 KB`  :(

Comment: Can you quote the question? Maybe it asks you to implement an algorithm with very stringent memory requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was writing a comment but it was getting too long, so I think I might as well upgrade it to an answer.

First off, the `profile` decorator uses quite a bit of memory just by itself. As you can see:

```
from memory_profiler import profile
@profile
def foo():
    pass
```

and I get

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    2     28.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    3                             def foo():
    4     28.5 MiB      0.0 MiB       pass
```

Your number will probably vary (I'm running Python 3, in a IDE no less) but it's basically the same thing with your function. Almost all memory usage comes from the `@profile` line (10.520 MiB) and what's added by your function (see the Increment column) is trivial (0.36 MiB).

The upshot is that you shouldn't have any problem by the looks of it (if what you posted is already your entire code, and I suppose it is). I don't know what test case can possibly give you `Memory Limit Exceeded`. We really need to know what that test case is to investigate the problem.

That said, one improvement can make your code more efficient, especially for a large number of inputs. You don't need to build intermediate lists (`k` and `v` in your code). Write to the dict directly:

```
d = OrderedDict()
for i in range(int(n)):  # Note you don't need range(0, x); just range(x)
    a, b = raw_input().split()  # No need for an argument to split, either
    d[a] = b
```

Even better, you can avoid a `for` loop and use a more efficient generator expression:

```
d = OrderedDict(raw_input().split() for _ in range(int(n)))
```

A generator expression is an expression of the form `(foo something_like_a_for_loop)` (formal description [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression)); the surrounding parentheses can be omitted if it's the sole argument to a function. It's like a list in many ways: you can iterate it using `for`, you can get a list out of it using `list`, you can use it whenever an iterator is expected. But it takes a lot less space than an equivalent list when the list is long. (But there are also differences: a gen expr can be iterated over **only once**, can't be indexed and doesn't have `len`, etc. You can read more about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).)

There are other small improvements you can make. All incorporated into the rewrite below

```
def test_1():
    n = int(raw_input('Enter the number: '))
    d = OrderedDict(raw_input().split() for _ in range(n))
    sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k_v: int(k_v[1]), reverse=True)
    for i, j in sorted_items:
        print i, j
```

Comment: thank you for explaining me and helping me in giving me a little more efficient solution. I'll understand that and learn it. I really don't know what that test case is as it's an online judge that checks the code with their own test cases. So its close to impossible to get that particular test case. But let me give a try with this solution and see where it leads to.

Comment: and that's the complete solution I provided

Comment: @Dev Another thing since you're on python 2: use `xrange` instead of `range`. `range` creates the whole list at once and could be huge; `xrange` (which becomes just `range` in python 3) returns one value a time and takes up negligible memory: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

Comment: thank you. will do that. and i have couple of queries. could you please clarify. firstly - `d = OrderedDict(raw_input().split() for _ in range(n))` what exactly is happening in this function. I'm more of step by step writer but this is very precise but i'm not able to get it. and second one - `key=lambda k_v: int(k_v[1])` what does the `_` do here ?

Comment: @Dev `k_v` is just an ordinary identifier. I use `_` to remind myself that its value is a 2-tuple. It has no other significance. Your `lambda (k, v)` is in fact perfectly fine in python 2, but it's [not allowed in python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), so it's better to get yourself used to nothing using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104008/discussion-between-gill-and-dev).